# Create javascript object with image as property

Tags: javascript, image, object, onload

I am relatively new to javascript, I have only programmed in Python before and I am having difficulties to create an object instance in this language.

```
class SteeringWheel {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.can = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.ctx = this.can.getContext('2d');
    this.img = new Image();
    //some img
    this.img.src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41iNBF9Q%2BsL._SX425_.jpg";
    this.img.onload = function() {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    }
  }

var st = new SteeringWheel('st1')
```

But the error following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined
```

I tried to nest the onload function but it does not work.

```
this.ctx.onload = function() {
   this.img.onload = function() {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

In my .html file there is a canvas with the id 'st1'. After I call the script written above.

The reason why I created an object is because my future intention is to call:

```
var st = new SteeringWheel('st2')
var st = new SteeringWheel('st3')
```

and have several instances of the same object.

It is probably a stupid question but I am completely blocked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
   this.img.onload = () => {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    }
```

Because happening `this` = `this.img`. This is true when used with the old `function () {}` method. But this does not apply when the **arrow function** is used.

Comment: Please vote to close when a duplicate question is asked.